# How to put a list of tensor into a new tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor

How can I merge a list of tensor into a single tensor?

I have a list of 64 images (128x128, RGB), and I want to create a batch of images with this size: `torch.Size([64, 3, 128, 128])`

I tried with `torch.stack()` but I can't get all elements of the list without iterating it.

How can I do it?

```py
lfw_dataset = ImageFolder(os.path.join(root_dir), transform=test_transform)
lfw_dataset_train, lfw_dataset_val = torch.utils.data.random_split(lfw_dataset_train1, [train_values, validation_values])
train_loader = DataLoader(lfw_dataset_train, batch_size, num_workers=4, shuffle=True)
val_loader   = DataLoader(lfw_dataset_val,   batch_size, num_workers=4, shuffle=False)
# Define dictionary of loaders
loaders = {"train": train_loader,
           "val": val_loader}
 
positive_list= []
negative_list= []
positive_img = []
negative_img = []
for i, (input, labels) in enumerate(loaders["train"]):
  for num, x in enumerate(labels):
    target = x.item()
    k = [i for i, (imgs, label_pos) in enumerate(lfw_dataset.imgs) if label_pos==target]
    group_pos = (target, k)
    positive_list.append(group_pos)
    for i, (imgs, label_neg) in enumerate(lfw_dataset.imgs):
       if label_neg!=target:
         j = [i]
       break
    group_neg = (target, j)
    negative_list.append(group_neg)
    anchor_img=input[num]
    positive = random.choice(positive_list[num][1])
    negative = random.choice(negative_list[num][1])
    positive_img.append(lfw_dataset[positive][0])
    negative_img.append(lfw_dataset[negative][0])
```

Comment: What's the problem with iterating if you can get all elements this way?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly `torch.stack()` should work. Can you show the code that you tied?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because torch.stack() requires all elements in one run

Comment: @Akavall sure, i put it here: https://pastebin.com/SmUKkKLQ

Comment: @Akavall as you can see, I create a list of positive and negative images, but now I have to create a batch of this (so, I have to create a tensor with that size)

Comment: Hi i think u can use `torch.cat` with dim = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use torch.cat(input1, input2, dim)